# How to find all classes (types) that are implemented a nested interface in C# .NET Core?

Tags: c#, reflection, system.reflection

Please consider the following sample:

```cs
    public interface IRepository<T> {} // NESTED

    public class Student {}
    public class Person  {}

    public interface IStudentRepository : IRepository<Student> {}
    public interface IPersonRepository : IRepository<Person> {}

    public class StudentRepo : IStudentRepository {}
    public class PersonRepo : IPersonRepository {}
```

I want to find all classes (`StudentRepo` and `PersonRepo`) that are implemented `IRepository<T>` in C# (.NET Core 3+).

When I use `IStudentRepository` or `IPersonRepository` to find types, everything is OK but does not work by searching `typeof(IRepository<>)`!

this block of code **returns nothing**

```cs
var repoTypes = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
                .Where(x => x.GetInterfaces().Containes(typeof(IRepository<>)))
                .ToList()
                ;
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> this block of code returns nothing

Because none of you repositories implements open generic interface `IRepository<>`, they implement constructed ones (`IRepository<Student>`, `IRepository<Person>`). You need to check your type's interfaces for being generic (`Type.IsGenericType`) and having it's generic type definition (`Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition()`) being equal to `typeof(IRepository<>)`:

```
var repoTypes = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
    .Where(x => !x.IsInterface && x.GetInterfaces()
        .Any(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IRepository<>)))
    .ToList();
```